# Order By inside a left outer join giving random results

Tags: mysql, sorting

I cannot get a sort on a Left Outer Join table to work. The result should be `3900000` however I can only get sorting to work on the `players` table and not the joined table `price`

```
SELECT price FROM price where id = 301;
+---------+
|  price  |
+---------+
|  100000 |
| 3900000 |
+---------+
```

As you can see below, currently my query is returning the lowest of the prices. I would like the result to be `3900000` in this example.

```
SELECT t.price FROM players s LEFT OUTER JOIN price t on t.id = s.id where t.id = 301 group by s.id order by s.rating desc, t.bod desc;

+---------+
|  price  |
+---------+
|  100000 |
```

Is this possible in MySQL?

Comment: *FROM price order where* this cannot possibly compile and I have no idea what you are asking, your second query is also unusual with a group by but no aggregation.

Comment: Ye, thats a typeo in that first query `order`. I've added some extra information in the question. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: The join condition seems wrong: Are you sure it isn’t `on t.player_id = s.id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `MAX()`:

```
SELECT MAX(t.price)
FROM players s
LEFT OUTER JOIN price t on t.id = s.id
WHERE t.id = 301
```

Or more simply:

```
SELECT MAX(price)
FROM price
WHERE id = 301
```

---

I suspect the column name in `price` should be `player_id` instead of `id`

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian! Well, that entire structure was actually just made up to try and illustrate my concept. Here is the actual query. I will look into max and see what it does :) Thank you Holy smoke it works. So how does that work? An internal seperate query?